# Correct approach to multiple queries Go Rest API

Tags: go

I am attempting to create a REST API in Go. I have it partially working in that it will return 4 separate json objects like such:

```
[{"Name":"QA1","Server":"BOT1","Description":"Tools","Apps":""},
{"Name":"QA1","Server":"","Description":"","Apps":"Duo"},
{"Name":"QA1","Server":"","Description":"","Apps":"Git"},
{"Name":"QA1","Server":"","Description":"","Apps":"php"}]
```

What I want is a single returned object like:

```
[{"Name":"QA1","Server":"BOT1","Description":"Tools","Apps": "Duo|Git|php"}]
```

I obviously have the way that I am either making my queries or the structs (or both or something else) not quite correct. I want to make sure I understand how to do this right because I would like to expand on it for other queries and such down the road. I have included the "full" go code below.

To be clear, I'm not simply looking for the solution (though I would of course appreciate that to compare with), but where I've gone wrong in my thinking and what the correct approach would be.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// There can be zero or more apps on a volume
type Apps struct {
    Name string
}

// Volumes have a name, description, are on a server and have multiple services/apps
type Volume struct {
    Name        string
    Server      string
    Description string
    Services    Apps
}

//Handle all requests
func Handler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    response.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
    webpage, err := ioutil.ReadFile("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(response, fmt.Sprintf("home.html file error %v", err), 500)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(response, string(webpage))
}

// DB Connection
const (
    DB_HOST = "mydbhost"
    DB_NAME = "mydb"
    DB_USER = "mydbuser"
    DB_PASS = "mydbpass"
)

// Respond to URLs of the form /api
func APIHandler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    //Connect to database
    dsn := DB_USER + ":" + DB_PASS + "@" + DB_HOST + "/" + DB_NAME + "?charset=utf8"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Open doesn't open a connection. Validate DSN data:
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    //set mime type to JSON
    response.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/json")

    result := []*Volume{}

    switch request.Method {
    case "GET":
        srvrnm := request.URL.Query().Get("srvrnm")
        appnm := request.URL.Query().Get("appnm")
        srvrs, err := db.Prepare("select VOLUMES.name as volnm, SERVERS.name as srvrnm, VOLUMES.description as descr From VOLUMES LEFT JOIN SERVERS ON VOLUMES.server_id = SERVERS.id where SERVERS.name = ?")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }
        srvcs, err := db.Prepare("select VOLUMES.name as volnm, SUPPRTSVCS.name as app_name From VOLUMES as VOLUMES JOIN HOSTSVCS ON VOLUMES.id = HOSTSVCS.volume_id JOIN SUPPRTSVCS ON SUPPRTSVCS.id = HOSTSVCS.supportsvcs_id where VOLUMES.name = ?")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }

        // Run the SQL Query to Get Volum & Description From Hostname
        srvrrows, err := srvrs.Query(srvrnm)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }
        for srvrrows.Next() {
            var volnm string
            var srvrnm string
            var descr string
            // Scan the First Query
            err = srvrrows.Scan(&volnm, &srvrnm, &descr)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error scanning: " + err.Error())
                return
            }
            // Append Slice with results from the scan
            result = append(result, &Volume{Name: volnm, Server: srvrnm, Description: descr})
        }

        // Run the SQL Query for Services/Apps
        srvcrows, err := srvcs.Query(appnm)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }

        for srvcrows.Next() {
            var volnm string
            var appnm string
            // Scan the Second Query
            err = srvcrows.Scan(&volnm, &appnm)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error scanning: " + err.Error())
                return
            }
            // Append Slice with results from the scan
            result = append(result, &Volume{Name: volnm, Apps: appnm})
        }
    default:
    }

    json, err := json.Marshal(result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(response, string(json))
    db.Close()
}

func main() {
    port := "1236"
    var err string

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/api", http.HandlerFunc(APIHandler))
    mux.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(Handler))

    // Start listing on a given port with these routes on this server.
    log.Print("Listening on port " + port + " ... ")
    errs := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, mux)
    if errs != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe error: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it about making the desired structure that you're unsure about?

Comment: Aside from your question, I believe you are getting an error that isn't being caught. You call `defer db.Close()` and then explicitly `db.Close()` at the end of your handler. The deferred function is going to return an error because the `db` will already be closed, but you won't see it because it's deferred.

Comment: Also based on your example data you only have one result from the first query, and 3 from the second query, but it's unclear what should happen if there are multiple results from the first query.

Comment: @Adrian I am not sure how to combine the results of both queries or combine the queries into one, whichever would be better. I also had not thought of multiple results from the first query.

Gavin Thank you for catching that. The db.Close() has been commented out.

Comment: You need to know what your desired result is before anyone will be able to help you achieve it.

Comment: @Adrian - I believe I gave the desired result as an example. Maybe I wasn't clear, but I want to see this output: [{"Name":"QA1","Server":"BOT1","Description":"Tools","Apps": "Duo|Git|php"}]

Comment: Except, as you just stated, you "had not thought of multiple results from the first query".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you want to your result to look like:

```
[
  {"Name":"QA1","Server":"BOT1","Description":"Tools","Apps": ["Duo","Git","php"]
]
```

Hence you want your Volumes struct to look like:

```
type Volume struct {
    Name        string
    Server      string
    Description string
    Services    []Apps
}
```

*If you want the Apps to actually output* `Duo|Git|php` *then you could create a custom type instead of `[]Apps` with a JSON [Marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) implementation. This could simply return `json.Marshal(strings.join(names,"|"))`*

Rather than run two separate queries, it would be more efficient to run a single query that selects the product of volumes & apps together. It is important that this query is sorted by volume so all volume rows are contiguous. Example query output would be:

```
Name | Server | Desc  | App
---- | ------ | ----- | ---
Vol1 | Srv1   | Desc1 | App1 
Vol1 | Srv1   | Desc1 | App2
Vol2 | Srv2   | Desc2 | App3
```

You would then loop over this and detect if you are looking at a new volume. If so, create a new entry in the result. If not, add the App to the list of apps. For example:

```
var (
   volnm string 
   srvrnm string
   descr string
   appnm string 
   v     *Volume
   result []*Volume
)

for srvrrows.Next() {
    if err = srvcrows.Scan(&volnm, &srvrnm, &descr, &appnm);err!=nil {
       // Handle error
    }

    // Add App to current volume if same, otherwise start a new volume
    if v!=nil && v.Name == volnm {
       v.Services = append(v.Services,Apps{appnm}) 
    } else {
       v = &Volume{
          Name: volnm, 
          Server: svrnm, 
          Description: descr, 
          Services: []Apps{appnm}}
       result = append(result,v)
    }
}

// Finished, return result etc...
```

When taking this approach, you need an appropriate parent record discriminator. I'd just used `v.Name == volnm` for illustration purposes but this should really be checking the **primary key**. You can make this an unexported (lowercase) field in the struct if you do not wish to export it through the API.

Comment: Ah. yes, you are correct, that would be a more appropriate result. Now, if I want to extend this further, keep adding to the same single query?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible. It depends on how much data you are going to be returning. The alternative is to write prepared statement(s) that you execute inside the loop for each record and have a 2nd inner loop to read the result. This will be slower as it involves more round trips to the server which has to run another query. However, if you are returning large amounts of child data and limiting the number of parent rows in a result (e.g. 50 max) then this could be more efficient as you are not wasting time transmitting & reading in all the parent row columns that you use only once.