# Golang db.Query with sql join

Tags: mysql, join, go

I would like to query for a `question` and all of its `answers`. The following two functions work just fine. The problem is I think this should be done in one function, with one query. (I removed error checking for brevity).

```
func QuestionById(id string) (*Question, error) {
    question := new(Question)
    _ = db.QueryRow("select * from question where question.id = ?", id).Scan(
        &question.Id,
        &question.LessonId,
        &question.Body,
        &question.Type,
    )

    return question, nil
}

func AnswersByQuestionId(id string) ([]*Answer, error) {
    rows, _ := db.Query("select * from answer where question_id = ?", id)
    defer rows.Close()

    answers := make([]*Answer, 0)

    for rows.Next() {
        answer := new(Answer)

        _ = rows.Scan(&answer.Id, &answer.Body, &answer.QuestionId, &answer.Correct)

        answers = append(answers, answer)
    }
    _ = rows.Err()

    return answers, nil
}
```

I would like to use a join query in this way (or something similar):

```
func QuestionByIdAndAnswers(id string) (*Question, []*Answer error) {
    rows, _ := db.Query("select * from question join answer on question.id = answer.question_id where question.id = ?", id)

    // more stuff here

    return question, answers, nil
}
```

Comment: There was a similar question about this not long ago. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374658/correct-approach-to-multiple-queries-go-rest-api/45375727#45375727) which describes how to populate a struct using a primary key as a discriminator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general it must be something like this:

```
func QuestionByIdAndAnswers(id string) (*Question, []*Answer, error) {
  query := `
    SELECT q.id, q.body, a.id, a.question_id, a.body
    FROM question AS q
    JOIN answer AS a ON q.id = a.question_id
    WHERE q.id = ?
  `
  rows, err := db.Query(query, id)
  checkErr(err)

  question := &Question{}
  for rows.Next() {
    answer := &Answer{}
    err = rows.Scan(
      &question.ID,
      &question.Body,
      &answer.ID,
      &answer.QuestionID,
      &answer.Body,
    )
    checkErr(err)
    question.Answers = append(question.Answers, answer)
  }

  return question, question.Answers, nil
}
```

Please pay attention, I intentionally replaced:

`SELECT *` to `SELECT q.id, q.body, a.id, a.question_id, a.body`

with purpose to avoid errors like:

`panic: sql: expected 6 destination arguments in Scan, not 5`

which may occur when some columns added or deleted from table, so this query more robust.

And this is just basic implementation, you can extend it with more fields...

PS: Function `checkErr` also omitted for brevity.

Comment: Let's say the question table is really big and has over 20 columns whereas the answer table has only 3 or 5 columns. When you join two tables you will retrieve the same question information which allocates unnecessary memory both on `golang` side and the `DB` side, because every row includes duplicate question information only answer information differs for each row. Maybe sometimes running two queries make sense right? What is your personal opinion about repeating the same data for each row?